# Unrecognized selector on custom subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, unrecognized-selector

I spent some time looking around other similar posts but was unable to find my exact problem. I'm new to iOS and objective c so it's probably very simple.

I'm subclassing UICollectionViewCell:

```
@interface FooCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
@end
```

And in my custom subclass of UIViewController, i'm trying to set a value for `cellLabel`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        FooCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = @"whatever";
    cell.cellLabel = label;

    return cell;
}
```

My app crashes when run:

> [UICollectionViewCell setCellLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fef224144f0

If I'm understanding that error, it looks it's complaining that i'm trying to set the cellLabel property on an instance of UICollectionViewCell the superclass instead of an instance of FooCollectionViewCell the subclass.

However, when I add a breakpoint at that line and look at my variables, I see:

> cell   FooCollectionViewCell * 0x7fcb5340dcd0  0x00007fcb5340dcd0

It also seems obvious from my code that the object has to be of type FooCollectionViewCell because that's the type `cell` is instantiated as.

My process for setting up my storyboard was:

1. Drag a CollectionViewController to my storyboard
2. Set its Custom Class to FooCollectionViewController. This seems to work because my code is called.
3. Click the prototype cell automatically created within the automatically created Collection View, set its Custom Class to FooCollectionViewCell. Set the Identifier to "FooCell", and update the reuseIdentifier variable in my ViewController to also be "FooCell".

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: In your storyboard/NIB have you set the Custom Class of your "Table View Cell" to FooCollectionViewCell for the one with your reuse identifier?

Comment: Are you using storyboard or using custom .xib if you are using .xib then you have to register your nib in viewdidload method. I think that cell is making but it is not assigning value try to clean build your folder and reset you simulator then it will solve your problem

Comment: One cannot see in your code, which class is used to create the cell instance. The type of the reference var `cell` is without any meaning. What have you set i your xib/SB? Please add a check on the class of the cell in your code to see, if another class instantiates the cell object.

Comment: @Tom, yes reuse identifier matches and Custom Class is set properly in my storyboard. Although if the reuse identifier didn't match I wouldn't expect this code to be called at all, correct? And if the custom class didn't match FooCollectionViewCell I would expect the dequeReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier call to fail with a type error?

Comment: No, that wouldn't cause it to fail. You're just telling the compiler that you expect the cell to be a FooCollectionViewCell, and the compiler assumes you know what you're doing. You ned to answer Tom's question; that's most likely the problem.

Comment: @rdelmar okay I had assumed that the assignment would fail if the types don't match, that probably means I've configured something wrong elsewhere and the deque command actually is giving me an instance of UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: Yes it is. Your problem is as Tom suggests.

Comment: Added an explanation of my storyboard set up process to see if anything obvious is missing from there. I'm basically following http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you say that you follow tutorial. So have you done these steps?

> With the basic collection view classes implemented and associated with the storyboard objects, it is now time to design the cell. This is, quite simply, a matter of dragging and dropping items from the object library onto the prototype cell in the storyboard view. Additionally the size of the cell may be modified by selecting it and using the resulting resize handles. The exact design of the cell is entirely dependent on what is to be displayed. For the purposes of this example, however, each cell is simply going to display an image.

Because you are creating a new label in the code, when it should be already available in prototype cell. You only have to assign cell.cellLabel.text = @"bla bla";

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"whatever";
cell.cellLabel = label;
```

Comment: even that wasn't working. The problem was that I had a conflicting statement in code registering the UICollectionViewCell super class with my reuse identifier. What you mentioned was a second problem I had that I needed to do in order to actually see the text change

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When I created my view controller subclass the file automatically had

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

in my viewDidLoad method. So I think that was overriding what I was doing in my storyboard. FML but I learned something. Thanks for the help!

The fix was to remove this line since I'm configuring that in my storyboard.